# Unplugged pi while installing LibreOffice, now won't load desktop environment

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, lxde

I was installing LibreOffice on my Pi and after around 2 hours of waiting it appeared as if it frozen. The mouse would still respond but the entire desktop environment had hung. So I unplugged it then plugged it back in, now it reaches the point where the desktop environment is supposed to load then shows a black screen. After that the console cursor starts flashing and doesn't stop.

Comment: Sounds like you managed to interrupt the installation at a point where it was affecting a system file that the X server also uses. Do you get the boot messages? Try pressing shift while the Pi is booting and telling me what happens.

Comment: I managed to log into my pi's command line and I believe the memory is full. During boot I get a warning (while it's mounting /tmpfs) that the system has insufficent space. Also I typed dpkg --configure -a and it's resumed what it was doing previously, but now saying that there is insufficent space also, and "failed to write hash table".

Comment: Attempting to fire up startx returns a "no protocol specified"

Comment: @RPi_Awesomeness Found the problem. I hadn't expanded the filesystem

Comment: Ah. Glad to see you resolved this on your own. Like Steve said, it's good that you're answering your own question - but it would be better if you added the information you commented about the lack of space. The lack of space is definitely an issue. I had a similar issue on an Ubuntu PC when I had a very small amount of space left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installation of LibreOffice had hung the system because it was out of space. During boot-up, there were a number of warnings that popped up about insufficient space and files failing to be created. The space issue had resulted in the desktop environment not loading up after the boot completed. I solved this by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F1 after boot completed and launched raspi-config. From this menu I expanded the filesystem to fill the entire SD card. I rebooted and was greeted with the desktop environment.